# How to see the commands executed by hotkeys

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

## Problem

Not sure if this exists or not, but I'm looking for a way to see what commands are being sent to the OS whenever I press some combination of hotkeys.

## Reason

I have mapped (via [cerebro](https://cerebroapp.com/)) `cmd+ctrl+f` to make the application fullscreen, and this works for most applications. However, for some applications (like Joplin), it does not work. My thinking is that the hotkey is mapped to something else at the application level (though I cannot confirm this). I would like to be able to see what my "computer" (applications, OS etc) "hears" whenever I execute some key combination

Comment: Cmd/ctrl/F is already the system default for fullscreen - but it requires that apps are ready for it.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean "apps are ready for it"? How do I go about making an app ready for it? It is open source, so if necessary I can go into the code

Comment: I don't code, sorry, but I work in an environment where others do & I've seen apps before they're fully set up to be Mac toolbox compliant. If you need code assistance you need to be on Stack Overflow itself.